# How can I get the object just after saving in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am saving the new object using

```
    new_document = form.save(commit=False)
    new_document.object_id = int(self.kwargs['pk'])
    new_document.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.target_model)
    # Set the document category
    new_document.category = self.get_document_category()
    new_document.save()
```

Now what is want to know is, after I save the object, how can I get the primary key of the object and other attributes?

Comment: Aren't id already in the object after save? Try new_document.id

Comment: Or new_document.pk in case your primary key field got another name

Comment: what is `self` in this code? from where is the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the object in `new_document`.